# CSS Property Stroke is clipping my letters for fonts in SVG

Tags: css, svg, fonts, stroke

Here is a screenshot of my font (default Arial Black Font):

[image: Example Image]

The bottom has fill while the top doesn't have any fill.
It gives the correct stroke to most letters but some letters have a clipped off part at the top left such as: E, F, H, I, etc... It basically cuts out a tiny square from some of the letters in their top left.

Any idea as to why it does this?
CSS is as follows,

Stroke: "black"
stroke-linecap: "butt"
stroke opacity: "1"
stroke-width: "2.5"
stroke-linejoin= "round"
paint-order= "stroke"

Comment: I'm not getting the same results for some reason. Could you post an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: Please improve your question with an [MCVE](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `stroke-linecap="round"`

```html
<svg x="0px" y="0px" width="162px" height="121.634px" viewBox="0 0 162 121.634">
 <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="3.654" y1="118.134" x2="90.646" y2="3.5"/>
 <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="90.646" y1="3.5" x2="158.5" y2="118.134"/>
 <line fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="7" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="158.5" y1="118.016" x2="3.5" y2="118.016"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: This is not exactly a fix. It is just disguising the problem. And square caps would be better than round here anyway.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau could explain more, please?

Comment: Firstly it is not clear what the exact fault is. OP should post an example snippet or fiddle. If you are right that caps will help disguise the problem then `stroke-linecap="square"` would be better than `round` because the corners are sharp.

Comment: This fixed it! When I use both stroke-linecap="round" and stroke-linejoin="round" it works! Thank you i'll make yours the answer.